# What does $d\log\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)$ mean mathematically?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, notation, logarithms, differential

I am used to seeing derivatives written as $$\frac{df}{dx}.$$

But my economics professor keeps using notation like $$ d\log\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)$$ and I have no idea what this means. What does this notation signify?

If it's a derivative, with respect to what? There is no denominator term. And I thought modern calculus used standard analysis with limits and not infinitesimals.

**my question:**

1. What does  $d\log\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)$ signify?
2. How do I take this derivative and with respect to what?

Comment: Can you provide a bit context around it?

Comment: It's a so-called differential with respect to the two real variables $x$ and $y$. The function you are differentiating to obtain the differential is $z = f(x,y) = \log \left( \frac{y}{x} \right)$, with respect to $x$ and $y$. The rule you use to compute it is given in Ivo Terek's answer below. It is, for your intents and purposes, essentially the usual multivariable chain rule.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In economics, the log differential (called elasticity) represents the differential percent change

$$d\log (x)=\frac{dx}{x}$$

of an economic variable.  For the elasticity of interest

$$d\log(y/x)=\frac{d(y/x)}{(y/x)}$$

which represents the percent change in the ratio $y/x$.  One can also express this as

$$d\log(y/x)=d\log (y)-d\log(x)=\frac{dy}{y}-\frac{dx}{x}$$

which represents the difference in differential percent changes.

---

If $U(x,y)$ is the utility function for consumption, then the elasticity of substitution is given by

$$\frac{d\log(y/x)}{d\log(U_x/U_y)}=\frac{\frac{d(y/x)}{(y/x)}}{\frac{d(U_x/U_y)}{(U_x/U_y)}}$$

where $U_x=\frac{\partial U}{\partial x}$, $U_y=\frac{\partial U}{\partial y}$, and $U_x/U_y$ is the marginal rate of substitution.

Comment: +1 Could you add a bit more and explain how to compute the elasticity of substitution $$\sigma = \frac{d\log\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)}{d\log\left(\frac{U_x}{U_y}\right)}$$?

Comment: excellent. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. My pleasure.

Answer (score 6):

If you have a function $f: \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$, say, $f(x_1,\cdots,x_n)$, then: $${\rm d}f = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}{\rm d}x_1 + \cdots + \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n}\,{\rm d}x_n. $$ In your case: $${\rm d}\left(\log\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)\right) = \frac{x}{y}\left(-\frac{y}{x^2}\right)\,{\rm d}x+ \frac{x}{y}\frac{1}{x} \,{\rm d}y = -\frac{1}{x}\,{\rm d}x + \frac{1}{y}\,{\rm d}y.$$

Comment: +1 This was nice and simple. Thanks for concision and quality.

Answer (score 1):

Are you familiar with the origin of the Leibniz notation, $\frac{{\rm d}y}{{\rm d}x}$? It comes from the derivation from first principles of the derivative being the limit of the gradient of secants of a function, where that gradient is calculated by measuring a change in $y$ relative to a change in $x$, i.e. $\frac{\delta y}{\delta x}$ as $\delta x \rightarrow 0$.

However, you can also look at something like $\frac{\rm d}{{\rm d}x}$ as being an operator which transforms a function to its derivative, so that $\frac{\rm d}{{\rm d}x} f(x) = \frac{{\rm d}f}{{\rm d}x}$.

And then we have integrals, which (at least if we're working with Riemann sums) are a limit of sums of areas of rectangles that approximate a function, as we make the width of the rectangles approach zero, i.e. $\int f(x) {\rm d}x$ is the limit of $\sum (f(x) \times \delta x)$ as $\delta x \rightarrow 0$.

So, in an incorrect but somewhat intuitive sense, ${\rm d}$ is somewhere between being "an infinitesimal change in something" and "an operator representing the basis of a derivative or integral".

So if you write ${\rm d}f(x, y)$, then you're trying to represent something about the behaviour of $f$, and in particular you can split that up as ${\rm d}f(x, y) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}{\rm d}x + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}{\rm d}y$, which is a bit more meaningful in the context of either a derivative or integral - for example, $\frac{{\rm d}f}{{\rm d}x} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{{\rm d}x}{{\rm d}x} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{{\rm d}y}{{\rm d}x} = f_x+y'f_y$ or $\int {\rm d}f = \int \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}{\rm d}x + \int \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}{\rm d}y$.

Answer (score 0):

Answers:

1. We have a function f, ant a point x for that function. Very often we can represent change of function value near this point lineary with respect to change of argument "A*dx" and with some infitine small error "|dx|*o(dx)" if dx->0. So that linear change without "error" is called differenial and is df

2a. 
In your case df should be linear relative to dx. 
It is exist a theorem that if you have a function and has partial derivatives by all variable and all of that partial derivatives and continious then the function is differentiable, and you can represent it as f(x+dx)-f(x) =A*dx+0(dx)*|dx|

2b. 
It is exist one more theorem that if function is diffeenretiable then f(x+dx) -f(x) = gradient(f) * dx + 0(dx)*|dx|

p.s. The mathematic discipline which cover that 2-nd question is differentional counting on multivariable functions.